How do I make a waterdrop shape using turtle in python?
Here is my code:
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()
t.width(5)

t.right(112.5)
t.forward(100)
t.circle(50, 225)
t.forward(100)
t.hideturtle()

It almost makes the correct shape, but the two points at the top don't meet each other.

Maybe the radius of the circle is wrong, or there are some other mistakes. Please fix my code

You needed to add more angle from the start and adjust the circle to get it right.
import turtle


t = turtle.Turtle()
t.width(5)


t.right(120)        
t.forward(100)      
t.circle(60, 240)   
t.forward(100)      
t.hideturtle()      

turtle.done()



For fun, we can throw parametric equations at this problem:
from math import pi, sin, cos
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

DELTA = pi/100

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(200, 200)
screen.setworldcoordinates(-1.1, -1.1, 1.1, 1.1)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.width(5)
turtle.penup()

theta = 0

while theta <= 2*pi:
    y = cos(theta)
    x = (1 - y) * sin(theta) / 2

    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.pendown()

    theta += DELTA

turtle.hideturtle()
screen.exitonclick()


